# Is there still need to use @Transactional annotation in Spring if the data store is MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, annotations

A typical Spring-MVC based CRUD application has the following layout.

the controller layer

```
@Controller
public class WebController{

     @Inject
     UserService userService;

     ...
}
```

the service layer

```
 @Service
 @Transactional
 public class UserServiceImpl{

      @Inject
      UserDao userDao;
 }
```

and the DAO layer

```
 @Repository
 public class UserDaoImlp{

      @Inject
      SessectionFactory session;
 }
```

With the use of Spring annotations, @Controller, Service, @Repository, and @Transactional, we can take the advantage the features from Spring. For example, if the data store is using a traditional database such as MySQL, the @Transactional annotation can help make sure the transaction is completed. But if I use the MongoDB as the data store, and MongoDB does not support transaction, is there still any advantage to use the @Transactional annotation? And how about @Service and @Repository layers?